# Does Pandas (natively) support mypy type hints?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-hinting, mypy

does pandas have support for mypy type hints? I want to type function that can recieve and return pandas Dataframe and Series. I have tried

```py
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame


def f() -> DataFrame:
    return {}
```

but I get

```sh
error: Skipping analyzing 'pandas': found module but no type hints or library stubs
```

If I silence this error by adding `type: ignore`, then the mypy runs without error, despite the function not returning a dataframe.
I have also tried:

```py
import pandas as pd


def f() -> pd.DataFrame:
    return {}
```

Same result, both with and without the `type: ignore` comment. I have tried this against pandas1.0.4, 1.0.5, current master on git ( @3e8f14f711642418c57a9e991f75ea86878020a3 ) and with both mypy 0.770 and 0.782.

Does pandas not support mypy type hints? Is there any way I can do this?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Note: I would like to do this with-in pandas+mypy only, external stubs exists like https://pypi.org/project/data-science-types/ but I would rather not depend on it

Comment: Odd! It keeps failing with `error: Skipping analyzing 'pandas.core.frame': found module but no type hints or library stubs` for me. I'll keep searching, thank you for time.

Comment: I was wrong, this fails for me as well, but it actually makes sense right? Mypy should not check the code of the module you're using.

Comment: @Georgy I've read that answer, but it's been three and a half year and both mypy/typeshed and pandas are in constant evolution, I hoped by now pandas was typing at least its public interface

Comment: @Erfan agree, mypy shouldn't check pandas - but shouldn't detect the error of returning a dict (or anything) when return type was annotated DataFrame? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please, see [Should I ask again something that's been asked a long time ago?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330546/7851470)

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14468

Comment: @Georgy I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of this nettiquette suggestion, what should I do? Delete my answer?

Comment: @Erfan thank you once again, as soon as I saw the issue I tried against master, but has the same result ... maybe it's not ready yet. Anyways I'll stick with the https://pypi.org/project/data-science-types/ package for now. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: @NicolasMartinez No worries! I think you can somehow accept the closure flag, if not, I'll ask in a [chat](https://socvr.org/) later. And no, you [shouldn't delete your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265736/7851470).

Comment: @Georgy thanks you for your patiente, even though I'm not a first time user, some "best-practices" I haven't grasped yet.. I flagged the duplicate and will post an answer to the original question, reflecting our discussion here

Comment: As of July 2022 check out https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs.